# How to get HTML text between H1 tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to parse an HTML document to extract all the H1 tags and all HTML between them. I have been playing with HtmlAgilityPack to achieve this with some success. I could extract all H1 tags using:

`foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1"))`

But how do I extract all the HTML after every H1 tag until I hit the next H1 tag? This HTML could include anything from a table/image/link or any other thing on an HTML page but H1 tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for a cookie cutter solution that doesn't exist. You can't just select all the XML elements between two random elements, not by any method I've ever heard of. What you could do is some sort of combination of NextElement with tree walking behavior, but you have to consider that an H1 could be nested, so you can't just get the next sibling element.

Comment: `H1`s aren't allowed to be nested, since `H1`s are only allowed to contain inline elements. An H1 is therefore also not allowed to contain a table. It is recommended, though not a standard, that there is only *one* H1 element in a document. If you control the HTML you should make it more, um, *sane*, before parsing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:
Get the complete HTML as String, replace < H1 > with a sign HTML does not know (e.g. ü, HTML uses & uuml;), then split the String by this sign into an array.

Now you search (with RegEx for example) for nodes that have start AND end tags and only parse those.

Quick and dirty, but should work.

Please be aware, that, as drachenstern mentioned, nested H1-Tags will lead to parent-nodes not being parsed.