# XPath select all elements between two specific elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a following xml:

```
<doc>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
</doc>
```

I want to select all p nodes after first divider element until next occurrence of divider element. I tried with following xpath:

```
//divider[1]/following-sibling::p[following::divider]
```

but the problem is it selects all p elements before last divider element. I'm not sure how to do it using xpath 1.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Same concept as bytebuster, but a different xpath:

```
/*/p[count(preceding-sibling::divider)=1]
```

Comment: Great idea! `count` is more idiomatic as the `1` is used only once.

Answer (score 21):

**Here is a general XPath expression**:

```
/*/divider[$k]
    /following-sibling::p
       [count(.|/*/divider[$k+1]/preceding-sibling::p)
       =
        count(/*/divider[$k+1]/preceding-sibling::p)
       ]
```

If you substitute `$k` with `1` then exactly the wanted `p` nodes are selected.

if you substitute `$k` with `2` then all `p` elements between the 2nd and 3rd `divider` , ..., etc.

**Explanation**:

This is a simple application of the *Kayessian* XPath 1.0 formula for node-set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

selects all the nodes that belong *both* to the nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`.

In this specific case we substitute `$ns1` with:

```
/*/divider[$k]/following-sibling::p
```

and we substitute `$ns2` with:

```
/*/divider[$k+1]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Answer (score 9):

I think there's a much simpler and probably faster solution: you want all preceding siblings of the second divider that have at least one preceding sibling divider:

```
/doc/divider[2]/preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::divider]
```

It gets a bit more complex, of course, if you want to find the paras between the second and third dividers: then you want something more like Daniel Haley's solution.

Comment: Allows start and end divider tags to vary so, for instance, one may select items between an `H1` and the first `TABLE`. Simple and flexible.

Answer (score 6):

What about selecting all `p` having exactly **one** element `divider` as `preceding-sibling` ?

```
//doc/p[preceding-sibling::divider[1] and not (preceding-sibling::divider[2])]
```