# Parsing HTML from a defined start point to a defined end point?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

I have some HTML:

```
<hr noshade>
<p><a href="#1">Some text here</a></p>
<p style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:120%;"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">This is some description</span></p>
<hr noshade> <!-- so <hr noshade> is the delimiter for me -->
<p><a href="#2">Some more text here</a></p>
<p style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:120%;"><span style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">This is description for some more text</span></p>
<hr noshade>
```

While parsing using nokogiri, I want to print information between each of these set of tags that are separated by my own delimiter `<hr noshade>`. So, the first block should print information between all "p" tags that lie between two `hr noshade` tags and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the accepted answer on [XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements)

I only have a semi-safisfactory solution

You can use this XPath expression:

```
.//hr[1][@noshade]
  /following-sibling::*[not(self::hr[@noshade])]
                       [count(preceding-sibling::hr[@noshade])=1]
```

for the first group between  `<hr noshade>` 1 and 2,

then,

```
.//hr[2][@noshade]
  /following-sibling::*[not(self::hr[@noshade])]
                       [count(preceding-sibling::hr[@noshade])=2]
```

for the elements between  `<hr noshade>` 2 and 3, etc.

What these expressions select:

1. all siblings of an `<hr noshade>`, specified by its position N
2. that have only N `<hr noshade>` previous siblings, i.e. positionned in the N'th group
3. and that are not `<hr noshade>` themselves

As it will select several elements between 2 `<hr noshade>`, you may have to loop on the results and extract data for each sibling element.

Anyone on a more generic solution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it makes some sense to me. I am now trying to imagine a more generic solution because the html file is auto generated by a software, so I wouldn't know the number of <hr noshade>'s that it might generate.

Comment: So, I tried this:

    path = '//hr[1][@noshade]/following-sibling::*  [not(self::hr[@noshade])][count(preceding-sibling::hr[@noshade])=1]'
    xpath = doc.xpath(path)

But I get an error on it as, "unexpected ']' after 'equal' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)"

Comment: CSS::SyntaxError?? I haven't tested with Nokogiri, only with Python's `lxml.html`

Comment: For the generic solution, you may count `<hr noshade>` first, and then generate as many XPath queries you need

Comment: what you tried is a valid XPath expression, I don't know why Nokogiri would want to interpret this as CSS selector

Comment: can you guide me with the xpath for counting the number of occurences of "<hr noshade>" tag?

Comment: `count(.//hr[@noshade])` should give you the number of `<hr noshade>`

Comment: so the hr[0] refers to the information between the first "hr noshade" tag and the second "hr noshade" tag, but it doesn't give me some information before the first "hr noshade" tag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38059/discussion-between-paul-t-and-rohan-dalvi)