# Selecting between 2 specific elements to get comments between closing and starting tag

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm currently trying to fetch the data of a simple XML-Sheet which contains data for translation use it's structured like this:

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string><!-- Comment1 -->
<string name="action_error">Something went wrong.</string>
<string name="action_menu">You've got the choice</string><!-- Comment2 -->
```

Sometimes there are comments after  to describe the content a bit more for the translator.
I'd like to get those, while I managed to write a comment, I couldn't manage to get 1 comment reliable ...

My idea is:
If I want to get a comment of "action_setting" for example I use xpath to select this area:

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>|AREASTART|<!-- Comment1 -->
|AREAEND|<string name="action_error">Something went wrong.</string>
<string name="action_menu">You've got the choice</string><!-- Comment2 -->
```

I already tried archieving this with this code:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('strings.xml');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    //foreach ($xpath->query("//string[@name='debug']/following::comment()[1]") as $comment)
    foreach ($xpath->query("/*/string[count(preceding-sibling::string[@name='debug'])=1]/comment()[1]") as $comment)
    {
        var_dump($comment->textContent." ");
    }
?>
```

As you can see the commented line is simply selecting every comment node after my specific element and picks the first one in row. The problem with this is that I can't make sure that the comment is really after the specific element or just the comment of an element a few lines later.(so if I'd like to get "action_error" it would give me "Comment 2" which belongs to "action_menu)

As you can see I tried already to select this desired area but it simply doesn't return anything when there's a comment.(My source: [XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements))

So I'd be grateful if you would explain me a solution for this problem I'm facing with comments between 2 specific elements.

Comment: Could you enhance your second example excerpt to actually contain what you would like to be retrieved? This is for testing.

Comment: Added comments. And explained the problem with my first way to get comments with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`following-sibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) in conjunction with a [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#Predicates).

**Get the text of the next comment**

```
(following-sibling::string|following-sibling::comment())[1][self::comment()]
```

Given a context node, for example the `string` with the `name` of `action_settings`:

- `(following-sibling::string|following-sibling::comment())`

  Selects all of the `string` and comment sibling nodes following the context.
- `[1]`

  Filters the node set to have all of the nodes' `position()` is `1`: in other words, it reduces the set to only the first node.
- `[self::comment()]`

  Filters the node set to have only comment nodes.

In summary, the above will return a node set consisting of either:

- A single comment node; the one we are interested in.
- An empty node set.

**Putting it to use in an example**

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<example>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string><!-- Comment1 -->
    <string name="action_error">Error</string>
    <string name="action_menu">Menu</string><!-- Comment2 -->
</example>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$next_comment_xpath = 'normalize-space(
    (following-sibling::string|following-sibling::comment())[1][self::comment()]
)';

$strings = $xpath->query('//string');
foreach ($strings as $string)
{
    $name = $string->getAttribute('name');
    $value = $string->nodeValue;
    $comment = $xpath->evaluate($next_comment_xpath, $string);

    echo "Name:    {$name}\n";
    echo "Value:   {$value}\n";
    echo "Comment: {$comment }\n\n";
}
```

The real work is done by `$next_comment_xpath` which uses the example location path given above. The `normalize-space()` is used two cast the node set to a string, for two reasons: firstly, casting to a string gets us the text content of the first node in the set, or an empty string if none and, secondly, it means [`evaluate()`](http://php.net//manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) can return a PHP string.

**Example output**

```
Name:    action_settings
Value:   Settings
Comment: Comment1

Name:    action_error
Value:   Error
Comment: 

Name:    action_menu
Value:   Menu
Comment: Comment2
```