# Count Only Preceding Topics : Xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xslt, xpath

I have the below XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <body>
       <division>
          <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          <Btopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Btopic</longtitle></Btopic>
          <Ctopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Ctopic</longtitle></Ctopic>
          <division>
             <Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1.1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
          </division>
         <Dtopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Dtopic</longtitle></Dtopic>
         <Etopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Etopic</longtitle></Etopic>
       </division>
    </body>
```

I am using `count(ancestor::division[last()]/*[contains(name(), 'topic')])  to get all * topics under body/division element.

My need is if I use my context from `body/division/division/Atopic` I wanted to get only preceding topics under body/division . So in that case only

```
<Atopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Atopic</longtitle></Atopic>
<Btopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Btopic</longtitle></Btopic>
<Ctopic><longtitle>TitleDiv1 Ctopic</longtitle></Ctopic>
```

and NOT

```
 <Dtopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Dtopic</longtitle></Dtopic>
 <Etopic><longtitle>TitleDiv2 Etopic</longtitle></Etopic>
```

since it is after the context node.

Pls suggest.

Comment: Post XSLT what you have tried so far....

Comment: use `../preceding-sibling::*`

Comment: I use Arbortext editor and not XSLT.

Comment: count(preceding::*[contains(name(), 'topic')])

Comment: Take all elements of body/division and iterate theme in foreach loop, your stop condition will be when of the next element will be equal to division.

Answer (score 0):

Your context-node: `//body/division/division/Atopic`

Your pure XPath Expression:

```
//body/division/division/Atopic
 /ancestor::division[last()]
  /*[contains(name(), 'topic')]
     [
      count(.| //body/division/division/Atopic/ancestor::division[1]/preceding-sibling::*[contains(name(), 'topic')])
      =
      count(//body/division/division/Atopic/ancestor::division[1]/preceding-sibling::*[contains(name(), 'topic')])
     ]
```

Detailed explanation here: [xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements)