# Xpath Get text after first html tag

Tags: python, html, xpath

There are next block

```
<div class="text">
  <h1>head1</h1>
    Text1 <br/><br/> text12  <br/><br/> text 13
  <h1>head11</h1>
    Text11
  <h3>head3</h3>
    Text2
</div>
```

How to get text after first H1 with ignore `<br/><br/>` as

```
Text1 
text12
text 13
```

I use Grab Python
page = g.doc.select('//div[@class="text"]/h3[1]/following-sibling::text()]')
Result is

```
Text1
text12
text 13
Text11
Text2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try selecting the `text()` that only has one preceding `h1` sibling...

```
//div[@class='text']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=1]
```

Another alternative is to try using the Kayessian method...

```
//div[@class='text']/h1[1]/following-sibling::text()[count(.|//div[@class='text']/h1[1+1]/preceding-sibling::text()) = count(//div[@class='text']/h1[1+1]/preceding-sibling::text())]
```

Here's a better [example and explanation of the Kayessian method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10859928/317052).

Comment: If some change xml
<div class="text">
  <h1>Headerh1</h1>
    Text1 <br/> after header1
  <h3>Headerh3.1</h3>
    Text2 <br/> after header3.1
  <h3>Headerh3.2</h3>
    Text3 <br/> after header3.2
  <h3>Headerh3.3</h3>
    Text4 <br/> after header3.3
</div>

How change //div[@class='text']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::h1)=1] for text after H1, Text1 <br/> after header1?