# PHP create recursive list of header tags from DOM

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to parse some HTML to create a nested navigation based on the headings in that document.

An array like this is what i'm trying to create:

```
[
  'name' => 'section 1',
  'number' => '1',
  'level' => 1,
  'children' => [
    [
      'name' => 'sub section 1',
      'number' => '1.1',
      'level' => 2,
      'children' => []
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'sub section 2',
      'number' => '1.2',
      'level' => 2,
      'children' => []
    ]
  ],
]
```

So if the document has a H3 after a H2 the code can then parse this and create a nested array with child elements for each successive tier of H headings

I guess it needs to do a few main things:

- Get all of the headings
- Recursively loop (H3 after a H2 should be a child in the array)
- Create the section number `1.1.1` or `1.1.2` for example

This is my code to extract the headings:

```
$dom = new \DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Extract the heading structure
$xpath = new \DomXPath($dom);
$headings = $xpath->query('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5|//h6');
```

I've tried to create a recursive function but i'm not sure on the best way to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to test as this will depend on how complex the HTML is and the specific pages you use.  Also as the code does a lot, I will leave it up to you to work out what it does as an explanation would go on for some time.  The XPath was created using [XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements) as a reference to pick out the data between two tags.  The test source (test.html) is merely....

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Header 1</h2>
    <h2>Header 2</h2>
    <h3>Header 2.1</h3>
    <h4>Header 2.1.1</h4>
    <h2>Header 3</h2>
    <h3>Header 3.1</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual code is...

```
function extractH ( $level, $xpath, $dom, $position = 0, $number = ''  )  {
    $output = [];
    $prevLevel = $level-1;
    $headings = $xpath->query("//*/h{$level}[count(preceding-sibling::h{$prevLevel})={$position}]");
    foreach ( $headings as $key => $heading )   {
        $sectionNumber = ltrim($number.".".($key+1), ".");
        $newOutput = ["name" => $heading->nodeValue,
            "number" => $sectionNumber,
            "level" => $level
            ];
        $children = extractH($level+1, $xpath, $dom, $key+1, $sectionNumber);
        if ( !empty($children) )    {
            $newOutput["children"] = $children;
        }
        $output[] =$newOutput;
    }

    return $output;
}

$html = file_get_contents("test.html");
$dom = new \DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new \DomXPath($dom);
$output = extractH(2, $xpath, $dom);
print_r($output);
```

The call to `extractH()` has few parameters.  As the sample HTML only starts with h2 tags (no h1) then the first parameter is 2.  Then the XPath and DomDocument objects to work with.

Comment: Thanks for this. The HTML is really simple, it's just basic P and H tags mostly. Your code seems to work nicely. I may have a H4 and H5 in there too, does this account for them too?

Comment: The code should go down till it runs out of H tags, so as long as they are nested one level down it should be OK ( i.e. H3->H4->H5 not H3->H5).

Answer (score 1):

accepted answer does not work for me with structure like this:

```
<h2>a</h2>
    <h3>aa</h3>
        <h4>aaa</h4>
            <h5>aaaa</h5>
                <h6>aaaaa</h6>
<h2>b</h2>
<h2>c</h2>
    <h3>ca</h3>
    <h3>cb</h3>
    <h3>cc</h3>
<h2>d</h2>
    <h3>da</h3>
        <h4>daa</h4>
            <h5>daaa</h5>
                <h6>daaaa</h6>
```

tree from  in the "d" section is being replaced with  tree from the "a" section

this solution works for me

```
class Parser {
    private $counter = [
        1 => 0,
        2 => 0,
        3 => 0,
        4 => 0,
        5 => 0,
        6 => 0,
    ];

    public function generate(string $text) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $tree = $this->extractHeadings(2, $xpath, $dom);

        return $tree;
    }


    private function extractHeadings($level, DOMXPath $xpath, DOMDocument $dom, $position = 0)  {
        $result = [];
        $prevLevel = $level-1;

        $query = "//*/h{$level}[count(preceding::h{$prevLevel})={$position}]";
        $headings = $xpath->query($query);

        foreach ($headings as $key => $heading) {
            $this->counter[$level]++;
            $item = [
                'value' => $heading->nodeValue,
                'level' => $level,
                'children' => [],
            ];
            $children = $this->extractHeadings($level+1, $xpath, $dom, $this->counter[$level]);
            if (!empty($children))    {
                $item['children'] = $children;
            }
            $result[] = $item;
        }

        return $result;
    }


}

$text = "
    <h2>a</h2>
        <h3>aa</h3>
            <h4>aaa</h4>
                <h5>aaaa</h5>
                    <h6>aaaaa</h6>
    <h2>b</h2>
    <h2>c</h2>
        <h3>ca</h3>
        <h3>cb</h3>
        <h3>cc</h3> 
    <h2>d</h2>
        <h3>da</h3>
            <h4>daa</h4>
                 <h5>daaa</h5>
                     <h6>daaaa</h6>
";

$parser = new Parser();
$parser->generate($text);
```

but still expects ordered headings though