# XPath query is Slow

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

I followed the way of this post to select all elements behind divider element, but it is slow with large xml file.
[XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements)

My code :

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= countDivider; i++) {
                 NodeList listmember =(NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/*/p[count(preceding-sibling::divider)="+i+"]",
                    doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    }
```

XML file demo:

```
doc>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
    <p>text</p>
    <divider />
</doc>
```

I used `/*/p[count(preceding-sibling::divider)=i]` but it is slow with large xml file(1000 `<divider>` and 12k `<p>`).

Comment: Did you try Dimitre's example of the Kayessian method in the linked question? It should look something like: `xpath.evaluate("/*/divider["+i+"]/following-sibling::p[count(.|/*/divider["+i+"+1]/preceding-sibling::p) = count(/*/divider["+i+"+1]/preceding-sibling::p)]")`

Comment: Hmm...I mocked up a larger example file (4,864 `divider` elements and 9,728 `p` elements) and the Kayessian method was slower than your original method (20 seconds vs 4 seconds when `i` = 1234). You'll definitely need to test with your processor and see what the difference is.

Comment: Hi @DanielHaley, This is just my example xml file, the xml file I'm using is more complicated and takes a lot of time to run an xpath query.

Comment: Ok but did you try the other method? Was it also slow?

Comment: yes, it also slow