# XPATH substring before and after to return text between two html tags

Tags: html, xpath

```
<h4>Start here</h4>
<p>Text stuff 1</p>
<p>Text stuff 2</p>
<h4>Stop here</h4>
```

I am trying to use substring before and after in one query to grab all content between an h4 tag that has the text: "Start here" and then stops before the text "Stop here"

So my correct query would return the text:

```
Text Stuff 1
Text Stuff 2
```

Whatever variation of this query I use it doesn't seem to work:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//h4[contains, 'Start here'),'//h4[contains, 'Stop here')
```

Comment: I've changed my answer quite a bit, don't miss the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the nodes that directly follow a particular `<h4>`, where "directly follow" can be expressed as "the first preceding `<h4>` is the one we started at" (well, and the node in question is not an `<h4>` itself, of course).

This expression<sup>(*)</sup>

```
//h4[. = 'Start here']/following-sibling::*[not(self::h4) and preceding-sibling::h4[1][. = 'Start here']]
```

selects from this document

```
<body>
  <h4>Not relevant</h4>
  <p>Other stuff</p>
  <h4>Start here</h4>
  <p>Text stuff 1</p>
  <p>Text stuff 2</p>
  <h4>Stop here</h4>
  <p>Other stuff</p>
</body>
```

these nodes

```
<p>Text stuff 1</p>
<p>Text stuff 2</p>
```

You can extract/join their text values in the host application.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> could also be written as `//*[not(self::h4) and preceding-sibling::h4[1][. = 'Start here']]`, but that one has to check more nodes, i.e. *all* nodes in the document, as opposed to only the following-sibling axis of one particular node.

Comment: Thanks so much. How would I change the query so that it's looking for "text containing" rather the exact word? So instead of looking for "Start here" I am looking for "Star", as an example.

Comment: @Rich `h4[contains(., 'Star')]`