# Split a html page at specific nodes using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I often want to partition a scraped HTML page by splitting it at specific nodes. How can this be done with Scrapy and Python?

##### Example

I want a function `split()` that split some HTML response

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph for heading</p>
<h2>Section 1</h2>
<h3>Subsection 1</h3>
<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1 for Section 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 2 for Section 2</p>
<h3>Subsection 2</h3>
```

at each heading, resulting in the following output -- depicted as list of list of string, but other data structures (e.g. iterator over `SelectorList`) would be fine, too:

```
[
  ["<h1>Heading 1</h1>", "<p>Paragraph for heading</p>"],
  ["<h2>Section 1</h2>"],
  ["<h3>Subsection 1</h3>"],
  ["<h2>Section 2</h2>", "<p>Paragraph 1 for Section 2</p>", "<p>Paragraph 2 for Section 2</p>"],
  ["<h3>Subsection 2</h3>"]
]
```

As input, `split()` needs the response and the nodes specifying where to split the response. Ideally, these nodes are given as `SelectorList`, so that they can be specified via XPath, e.g.

```
split(response, response.xpath("//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]"))
```

Could [XPath select all elements between two specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859703/xpath-select-all-elements-between-two-specific-elements) be generalized to perform such a split at given nodes?